# Using javascript to trigger a link when another one is clicked

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, handler

I know how to create an onclick event handler to run a script. I want to know if it is possible to have two hyper links in an html doc, and then click one that would trigger another ( I would assume via per onclick event handlers and DOM ID's etc.)

Thank you.

Comment: i think this will help you:- https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/dispatchEvent.html

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to navigate the page to the second link's `href`:

```
targetLink.onclick = function() { document.location.href = sourceLink.href; };
```

Otherwise you can dispatch a click event, as Pranav mentioned:

```
targetLink.onclick = function() {
    var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    event.initMouseEvent("click");
    sourceLink.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```

See [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent) for details.

Comment: I didn't know "location" was an object. Thank you! Thank you @ Pranav as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think `click()` is IE specific. try on click of first hyperlink:

```
eval( document.getElementById('mylink2').href );
```

OR you can try :

```
document.getElementById(id).attachEvent('onclick',name_of_function); //(for IE)
document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click',name_of_function,false); //(for others)
```

to know more about Events [check this](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/dispatchEvent.html)

Comment: Why are you using `eval` there? Why not `document.getElementById('mylink2').getAttribute('href')` or something similar?

Comment: @Josh I think the `eval` was intended for href attributes containing a `javascript:` URI scheme identifier followed by some javascript code. In that case the `javascript:` part would be parsed as a label; the code should evaluate as intended.